How to send and url encoded form on supabase http_post database extension
I need to send a request to a restful api from Supabase postgreSQL database using http_post function, sending an urlencoded form in body.
I found no specific documentation on supabase: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/http
My specific need is to send this request using supabase http_post extension, to get an access token from microsoft (in Curl to show the parameters I need to encode as x-www-form-urlencoded:
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my tentant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token'\
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<my app client id>' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=api://<my scope>/.default' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=<my client Id secret' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'


I found no specific examples, but after further testing I managed to send an url encoded form using http post and get a valid response from the rest api POST:
select status, ("content"::jsonb)
 from
 http_post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my tenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/token',
 '{ "client_id": "<my clientId>", "grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_secret": 
 "<my client app secret>","scope":"api://<my scope>/.default" }'::jsonb
 );

Response:
[
 {
  "status": 200,
  "content": {
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "<token>",
  "ext_expires_in": 3599
 }
} 
]

The above example works with any POST request that requires an urlencoded form.
